# How can I make this ScaleAnimation work?

Tags: android, google-maps

closed.
I made it by myself using Timer and override the draw method after learned more from the book.

Answer (score 1):

Don't call `animation.startAnimation(animation)`. just call `startAnimation(animation);` or `this.startAnimation(animation);`

Comment: Animation animation = null;
 animation = new ScaleAnimation(2,4,2,4, 10animation.setDuration(3*1000);   
         startAnimation(animation);

Comment: sorry for last comment. I think it is because i can't pass in the circle to animatio to let it know the object need to animate.

Comment: of course this isn't going to work, you haven't told the `Animation` which `View` it should animate.  The proper call to initiate an `Animation` is `View.startAnimation(Animation a)`

Comment: Sorry. I want to do on the circle. Please!

Comment: Thanks. it will not be on the view. will be the circle on google map.

Answer (score 0):

`Animation` objects are used to animate `View` objects. If you are drawing the circle yourself in `view.onDraw()` then you should really just scale the circle yourself.

**Update**:  Animations objects are used to animate `Views` from the main thread of your application. The main thread is not the same as the UI thread and the `Animation` objects provide a nice way tell the UI thread to draw an animation from the main thread. However, `onDraw` is called from the UI thread so it doesn't really make sense to use an `Animation` object because the executed code is already in the scope of the UI thread.

**Update 2:** Here is an example of the proper way to execute a `ScaleAnimation`

```
float startScaleX = 1.0f;
float startScaleY = 1.0f;
float endScaleX = 2.0f;
float endScaleY = 2.0f;
Animation a = new ScaleAnimation(startScaleX, endScaleX, startScaleY, endScaleY);
a.setDuration(1000);

View view = findViewById(R.id.my_view);

view.startAnimation(a);
```

Notice that after I've created the `animation` object I call `view.startAnimation(a)`. It doesn't make sense to run an animation without attaching it to a view.

Comment: This is a View object, no? He extended View.

Comment: No if you look at the code `CircleOverlay` extends `Overlay` which is a child class of `java.lang.Object` -> http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/Overlay.html

Comment: @slayton, whoops.. didn't even see the class declaration before. Thought he hadn't included it.

Comment: LuxuryMode. You are 100% right. How can i do it here? Please.

Comment: slayton. Thanks very much. I want to it on google map with placemarker as a circle and ScaleAnimation.